# Caption with math gives undefined control sequence

Tags: captions

I'm trying to include a caption for a figure with two subfigures with quite some math. However, I get:

> Undefined control sequence

I've tried to replace the the `$` with `\begin{math}` and `\end{math}` but that only gave the error:

> Argument of \@caption has an extra }.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=t]{ResultsFlapWinglets}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=t]{ResultsFlapFences}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{The experiments have been carried out with freestream velocity $u = 30 m/s$, 
angle of attack $\alfa = 10\degree$ and flap deflection $\delta_{f} = 32\degree$.}
\label{fig:FenceResults}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Besides, use `siunitx` to format units, bith `m/s` and degree.

Comment: Two comments not related directly to the problem you're looking to solve: (i) The `\centering` instructions inside the `subfigure` environments are unnecessary because the graphs take up the full width of the subfigures. (ii) You may want to instruct LaTeX to create a bit more horizontal separation between the two subfigures. You could do so by inserting the instruction `\quad` or, better yet, `\hspace*{\fill}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in a command name.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it is just a simple typo:

Try `\alpha` instead of `\alfa` in your caption.

Comment: And it was that simple... Still, thanks a lot Cv4!